# PV Jacket Project

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy

I was hoping to get some guidance on a project I am working. I am building a jacket which will have PV panels on it which will be used to power different types of loads. At the moment, I am lost with how should I proceed.

The loads I want to power:
1. LED Strip: 12V 1M<=4.8W
2. Charge a Phone: 5V 1A
3. 2 Fans: 0.5W 2V 120mA
4. Flashlight
5. MP3 Player/Headphones: 5V 1A

The LED is a 5M strip. I intend to use half of it. I assume that cutting it in half would also half the voltage which would reduce the power by half as well.
The ratings I have provided were copied from the products' description.
I intend to use Lithium Ion rechargeable batteries.

How do I figure out the power of the solar panels? Just add the power of all my loads? Does anything else matter (efficiency)?

What should be the voltage of my batteries? Should I have a higher voltage of my batteries than I need so I don't discharge it below 20% of its capacity (for battery safety)?

Do I need a charge controller? Do I need to think about the rate of energy being produced? What if my loads consume energy faster than the PV panel can charge my battery?

Considering the difference between the current ratings of my loads, should I connect all my loads in a parallel configuration to avoid burning my components?

Anything else I should be considering?
I don't want to reorder components because I ordered the wrong things. Or buy different rated components because I didn't think things through.

Comment: Yes, do the sums, dude, but cutting the 5M (miles? m for metre) strip in half will halve the current required, not the voltage. Add up all the wattages to get total power required. Next have a look at a solar panel datasheet and figure out how many m² of panel you're going to have to wear. You're going to be constrained to walking in a certain direction so the panels face the sun.

Comment: More likely constrained to dragging a wagon covered with solar panels behind you.

Comment: "The LED is a 5M strip. I intend to use half of it. I assume that cutting it in half would also half the voltage which would reduce the power by half as well."  Don't assume that.  It probably won't halve the voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I figure out the power of the solar panels?

You will not be able to power everything at the same time with solar panels, even in bright sunlight. Just produce as much power as you can with solar and use it to charge your batteries.

> What should be the voltage of my batteries? Should I have a higher voltage of my batteries than I need so I don't discharge it below 20% of its capacity (for battery safety)?

I would probably stick to 1s, and then use boost converters as necessary for your loads. There are many devices designed to produce various voltages from a 1s lipo (3.7 to 4.2v). This eliminates the need for a balance charger.

> Do I need a charge controller? Do I need to think about the rate of energy being produced?

Yes you will need a charge controller.

> What if my loads consume energy faster than the PV panel can charge my battery?

You will need some kind of circuitry to shutdown the loads if the battery gets too low. Either a BMS, or VREGs with low voltage protection built in. If you don't have this your regulators will happily run your battery so low it will never re-charge. The loads WILL drain the battery faster than the PVs will charge it.

> Considering the difference between the current ratings of my loads, should I connect all my loads in a parallel configuration to avoid burning my components?

I'm not sure what you mean by this. Just give each load it's own VREG and connect those to the battery (or BMS). Each load will draw what it needs from the battery. It's a lipo, so the current should not be an issue (lipos can handle a LOT).

> Anything else I should be considering?
>   I don't want to reorder components because I ordered the wrong things. Or buy different rated components because I didn't think things through.

Based on your current skill level you should know that that is basically impossible. You're going to need to experiment. Just get started, you'll figure it out.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=charge+controller+connections&safe=strict&client=firefox-b-d&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=m3fR1r9lLxrb3M%253A%252C9k5HKQpORw39JM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSMDesZvo3KHMMvh-ZbhT54uWb57g&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjo3PTenZLiAhWIAGMBHeknBY4Q9QEwBHoECAYQDA&biw=1366&bih=654#imgrc=m3fR1r9lLxrb3M:  I found this schematic. From what you said,will my loads all be connected in series with voltage regulators? And with this setup, I won't burn any of my components?

Comment: The loads will be in parallel to each other.